# How do I display the caret symbol when the active class is applied to another 'li' item (i.e when the li item is clicked)

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am new to knockout and css and need some help regarding the following.

How do I display the caret symbol when the active class is applied to another 'li' item (i.e when the li item is clicked).

Below given is the implemented code.

```
<li class="" data-bind="css: { 'active': $index() == 0 }, visible: { true: $index() == 0 }">
<a data-toggle="tab" data-bind="attr: { href: '#' + CatID }">
<span data-bind="if: $index() == 0 ">
<span class="caret"></span>
</span></a>
</li>
```

Any help will be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [CSS pseudo elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) and specify the `content` property for the `active` class. Here in example of [`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before)

> `::before` creates a pseudo-element that is the first child of the element matched. It is often used to add cosmetic content to an element by using the `content` property.

```css
.active::before {
  content: '^'
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="active">Yahooooooo</li>
  <li>Test</li>
</ul>
```